# Unable to install ‘audio.whisper’ package from GitHub in RStudio despite correct Rtools installation

Tags: openai-whisper, rtools, remotes

**Problem Description:** I'm trying to install the audio.whisper package from GitHub in RStudio using the command remotes::install_github("bnosac/audio.whisper"), but I'm getting an error message that says “Could not find tools necessary to compile a package”.

**R Version:** R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)

**Rtools Version**: I have installed Rtools 4.4 (as indicated by the path C:\Rtools44\usr\bin).

**Error Message:** The exact error message I'm getting is “Could not find tools necessary to compile a package”.

**Code:**

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org/"))
install.packages("remotes")
install.packages("av")
remotes::install_github("bnosac/audio.whisper")
```

Steps Already Tried: I have tried adding the path to Rtools to my PATH variable in R using Sys.setenv(), and I have confirmed that the path to Rtools is included in your PATH by checking Sys.getenv("PATH"). I have tried reinstalling Rtools and restarting RStudio, but none of these steps have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not compatible:
R Version: R **version 4.3.3** (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Rtools Version: **Rtools 4.4** (as indicated by the path C:\Rtools44\usr\bin).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).